How to download .nitro-files from a website?
I want to download all the .nitro-files from a website, using DevTools console.
This is the code I allready have
(async function downloadNitroFilesFromNetwork() {
    // Überprüft ob die DevTools geöffnet sind & ob der Netzwerk-Tab ausgewählt ist
    if (!window.performance || !window.performance.getEntriesByType) {
        console.error("DevTools müssen geöffnet und der Netzwerk-Tab ausgewählt sein");
        return;
    }

    const nitroFiles = [];

    const entries = performance.getEntriesByType('resource');

    // Filtert Dateien mit .nitro-Endung heraus
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.name.endsWith('.nitro')) {
            nitroFiles.push(entry.name);
        }
    });

    // Lädt die .nitro-Dateien einzeln herunter
    for (const url of nitroFiles) {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        
        if (!response.ok) {
                console.error(`Failed to download ${url}: ${response.statusText}`);
                continue;
        }
        
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        const fileName = url.split('/').pop();
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = fileName;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }

    console.log(`Downloaded ${nitroFiles.length} .nitro files`);
})();

The website I want to download the files from, has CORS enabaled. I seams like the script dont get any Information because the output is: Downloaded 0 .nitro files
I tried CORS-Blocker-Extension and a Proxy-Server allready
